# Track Envelopes which have used “Change Signer” option

Tags: docusignapi

How to track Envelopes which have used “Change Signer” option in DocuSign API c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it's possible to do a search for (i.e., retrieve envelopeIds) for all envelopes where "Change Signer" event has occurred.  However, to determine whether the "Change Signer" event has occurred for a specific envelope, you can use the **Get Envelope Audit Events** operation (REST API):

```
GET https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/audit_events
```

If a "Change Signer" event has occured for the specified envelope, the API response will contain info about this event:

```
  {
    "auditEvents": [
        ...
        {
            "eventFields": [
                {
                    "name": "logTime",
                    "value": "2014-02-27T14:41:36.0380469Z"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Source",
                    "value": "web"
                },
                {
                    "name": "UserName",
                    "value": "John Doe"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Action",
                    "value": "Reassign"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Message",
                    "value": "John Doe reassigned the envelope to Mary Smith [marysemail@outlook.com] routing order 1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "EnvelopeStatus",
                    "value": "sent"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ClientIPAddress",
                    "value": "65.11.28.123"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Information",
                    "value": "Mary Smith [marysemail@outlook.com] routing order 1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "GeoLocation",
                    "value": ""
                },
                {
                    "name": "Language",
                    "value": "english (us)"
                }
            ]
            ...
        }
    ]
```

The response will contain info for all events that have occured for the specified envelope -- the "Change Signer" event is the one where **Action = Reassign** (as shown above). See the REST API guide (p127) for more info about the Get Envelope Audit Events operation (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf).